# CKEditor non-editable in textarea

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

TinyMCE has an option that lets you make items in the editor not editable but I cannot find anything similar for CKEditor.  Is there a way to make elements in the editor not editable?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the configuration like this:

```
config.readOnly = true;
```

Or

You can use `disabled` attribute in `textarea`.

See the documentation here [Read Only Mode](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_readonly)

Comment: That's kind of what I'm after but I need a way to make the editor still be editable but elements within the editor not editable.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `contenteditable='false'` on the element and CKEditor will handle it correctly as read only.

Works in 3.4+, 4 also definitely works, 5 probably does as well.

**Reference:**
This link has information on it [slightly out of date, but still applicable for the core concept]: 
(https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/CKeditor_3.x/Users_Guide/NonEditable_Contents)